Android Emulator crashes after installing Android Emulator hypervisor driver (AEHD)
I work on a Dell laptop with Windows 11 and use VSCode for programming. For the past few weeks, I've been having serious issues with the Android emulator, which sometimes crashes and causes the PC to restart (often with a BSOD).
The problems started when I installed the Android Emulator hypervisor driver to replace the Intel driver, which is now deprecated (from the official documentation: "Starting from emulator 33.x.x.x, HAXM is deprecated as Intel discontinues development of HAXM. The Android Emulator hypervisor driver (AEHD) replaces Intel HAXM on Intel Processors." -> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)
I followed the official documentation at the link above for the installation and made sure to disable all the features they suggest should be disabled (see in particular this section: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#disable-hyper-v) but with no results.
Has anyone noticed similar issues?
